# Using array-summation for UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make this formula global:

```
{=SUM(Array1*Array2)}
```

*Not because I need this exact formula, but because I am trying to figure out how the syntax works for UDF. I'm hoping that the result looks a little like this::*

```
Public Function UDF1(MyArray1 As Range, MyArray2 As Range)
UDF1 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyArray1 * MyArray2)
End Function
```

*But this doesn't work? Is there anybody who could help me use the correct syntax for UDF*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: You cannot multiply arrays using the `*` operator in VBA.

Comment: @SJR I am trying to make complicated functions that resemble the SUMPRODUCT formula.  Here's an example: {=DaysYear*SUM(((30+Data[K1])*HRT*Data[CH4 productivity])/(30*(Data[K1]+HRT))*Feed[Prim-FV/d]*Data[TS/FV])}

Comment: @Rory. How do I then multiply arrays in VBA?

Comment: Loop and multiply each element.

Comment: @Rory. I think this might be the solution I am looking for. I starting to get used to the programming translation of mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the UDF name in your UDF1 will also not work, so change the name.

You *could* wrap your formula in an Evaluate call like this:

```
Public Function testing(MyArray1 As Range, MyArray2 As Range)
    testing = Evaluate("SUM(" & MyArray1.Address & "*" & MyArray2.Address & ")")
End Function
```

Comment: That works alright. But the notation gets kinda complicated. Especially for more complex functions.